# How do I find a specific occurrence of a list element in a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I can find info about finding items in a list all day, but this one seems to elude forums (my guess is because there is an easier way to do this - some method I haven't learned yet).

I'm doing a practice problem and I can't figure this out: in my function, I need to check two lists to see if any of their items (which are strings) occur in the input (also a string). Moreover, if there are more than one occurrences, I need to identify the last one for my if statement to work.

Sorry - I know this is a terrible explanation but I'm having a hard time describing it. I'll show my code.

Note: I've only been programming for a couple of weeks. I'm trying to keep this within the scope of fundamentals if possible. Thanks a ton.

So this takes various Hungarian words and concatenates them with the proper suffix based on which type (front or back) of vowel is in the word (string input). The problem is words with two vowels in one or both lists - I can't figure out how to find the last instance of the list items in a given input string.

I've already tried playing around with the find method and using ranges - I concede that this is beyond the scope of my limited knowledge and I need help. Thanks again.

```
   front = ['e', 'é', 'i', 'í', 'ö', 'ő', 'ü', 'ű']
   back = ['a', 'á', 'o', 'ó', 'u', 'ú']

   def dative(word):
       for i in word:
           if i in front:
               return word+'nek'
           if i in back:
               return word+'nak'
```

For example: input "virág' should be output as "virágnak" but it is  hitting the 'i' as it is the first index occurrence and outputting "virágnek".

Comment: You have `i` in `front` and the 'i' is before the 'á' in your word so it seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works only for the first occurrence but you want it to work on last.

So try to reverse the string so that the first occurrence is actually the last in the selected string.

Example:

```
for i in reversed(word):
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice, simple fix!

Comment: Mark the question as 'Answered' for future references @goldmund

Answer (score 0):

As another answer already stated, you can reverse the word before iterating over the letters (using [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#reversed)).

I also suggest a few changes in your code to account for cases where there is no match found (I used a `break` statement to exit the loop):

```
front = ['e', 'é', 'i', 'í', 'ö', 'ő', 'ü', 'ű']
back = ['a', 'á', 'o', 'ó', 'u', 'ú']

def dative(word):
    suffix = ''
    for i in reversed(word):
        if i in front:
            suffix = 'nek'
            break
        if i in back:
            suffix = 'nak'
            break

    return '{}{}'.format(word, suffix)
```

This works as expected (I don't know if those are valid words, but they show that the function does what it is supposed to do):

```
>>> dative('virág')
virágnak
>>> dative('vireg')
viregnek
>>> dative('virug')
virugnak
>>> dative('vrg')            # no suffix added
vrg
```

You would need to give more examples to check if it really works as it should, but for this one example it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I think they implement best practices, which I know I need to start doing early. So I'm guessing the curly brackets in the return statement are concatenated when using the format method?

Comment: @goldmund The method [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) builds a new string and places the arguments inside it. You can also use `return word + suffix` for the same result in this case.